# Make fragment layout fullscreen in single activity approach in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigationview

I have been using the single activity approach and the navigation component.
My single activity has a bottom navigation view and one of the bottom view is a `RecyclerView`. Clicking on one of its items opens a fragment. Let's call it DetailsFragment
I would like DetailsFragment to be fullscreen such that the bottom navigation view is not visible anymore. DetailsFragment also has its own toolbar which should hide the activity toolbar as well.

I have read some suggestions to create another activity for DetailsFragment. Doing so is an option which comes with many complex issues as I will have to rewrite all the communications between DetailsFragment and MainActivity.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve the problem:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.detailFragment) {
            binding.bottomNavigation.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            binding.bottomNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```